# Conservation of mechanical energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

A ball of mass 200g is dropped from a height of 4.4m above the ground as shown in diagram. Calculate its speed when it is 2m above the ground by making use principle of conversation of mechanical energy.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not a homework help site*. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for “check my work” problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

The principle of conservation of energy says that energy cannot be created or destroyed, only transferred from one form to another.

In this problem, the two forms of energy you should consider are gravitational potential energy ($mgh$) and kinetic energy ($\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$).

At the start of the problem, the kinetic energy is $0$, as the ball is not moving. As such, the system's energy is entirely potential.

Now, consider when the ball is 2 meters above the ground. It still has potential energy, but now that it is lower ($h$ is smaller), it has less potential energy than at the start of the problem. Remembering that energy cannot be created or destroyed, there is only one other place it could have gone: to kinetic energy.

Knowing the value of kinetic energy, as well as the mass of the object, rearrange and solve for $v$, and you have your solution.